# Using Axios to resolve VueJS Route

Tags: vue.js, routes, frontend, axios

Routes in main.js

```
{
    name: 'match',
    path: '/match/:id',
    component: Match,
    props: true
},
```

And in the main component (separate file) that fires the GET request:

```
axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/match/" + id,
      crossdomain: true,
```

)}

Chrome tells me it's a 404. But when I open the provided link, it resolves and works?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing component Axios call to

`url: this.$router.push({ name: 'match', params: { id: id }})`

As per https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
this.$router.push("/match/" + id)
```

While 'this' is a Vue instance.
You need to use vue-router API to navigate inside your application, not axois.